# How to send more than one column in NSMUtableArray and how to implement it

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I want to pull results with 2 columns with NSMutableArray.
-"name" column --> use to show in tableview when user start to type something
-"address" colomn -->will be used to send to another view.

Here is what I do :

```
        @interface ViewController ()
        {
            ViewController *SampleViewController;
            NSMutableArray *totalStrings;
            NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
            BOOL isFiltered;

        }


        @implementation ViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [self createOrOpenDB]; ////Call database


            NSMutableArray* result=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            NSString *ask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM tb_001"];
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            const char *query_statement = [ask UTF8String];
            const char *dbpath = [_DBPath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_iDB) == SQLITE_OK){
                {
                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_iDB, query_statement, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                            NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];


                            //add your namefield here.
                            [result addObject:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx];

                        }

                        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                        sqlite3_close(_iDB);
                    }
                }
                totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
            }

Here is where I will use the first column

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

    if (searchText.length ==0){
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = YES;
        filteredStrings =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (NSString *str in totalStrings) {
            NSRange StringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (StringRange.location !=NSNotFound) {
                [filteredStrings addObject:str];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.myTableView resignFirstResponder];
}

//table view datasource and delegate methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isFiltered){
        return [filteredStrings count];
    }
    return [totalStrings count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    if(!isFiltered){
        cell.textLabel.text =[totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else{ //It is filtered
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return cell;
}




    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        //here I want to use result from another column (address)
        LadyGagaVC *dada =[self.storyboard 
        [dada setText:[resilt_from_anothercolomn objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }
```

How can I put it in the correct array and use it ?
I know I have to use for loop but right now I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSDictionary`, like this:

```
 NSString *nameField    = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
 NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

 NSDictionary *data = @{@"name":nameField,
                     @"address":addressField};
 //add your namefield here.
 [result addObject:data];
```

And then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        //here I want to use result from another column (address)
        LadyGagaVC *vc = ...
        NSDictionary *dic = totalStrings[indexPath.row];
        NSString *name = dic[@"name"];
        NSString *address = dic[@"address"];            
        //Use this values as you want...
    }
```

Or it would be better to make a class (model) , say, MyModel which will have two property:

```
@interface  MyModel : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *address;
@end
```

And instead of dictionaries use instances of `MyModel`. E.G.

```
MyModel *model = [MyModel new];
model.name    = nameField;
model.address = addressField;
[result addObject:model];
```

Comment: The problem is how to implement the first for loop above ?
If the first for loop is not implement, the tableview would not be shown.

Comment: I found it by adding 2 results and separate it. one result is for the table view, another result is for another viewcontroller. It works. But looked complicated. 

But the class model, i don´t know why it did not work. Where to put that class ? .h file ?

Comment: Btw. I strongly recommend you to use third party libraries for sqlite, like https://github.com/enormego/egodatabase
Your code would be much more clean and readable

Comment: Thanks for your great answer and recommendation.
I have one question: how to use the model.name  in "totalstrings" ?

Comment: Well, instead of `totalString` you should use different name, say, totalObjects. Each object in totalObject is kind of class `MyModel`, so 
`MyModel *model =  totalObject[someIndex]; 
model.name... `

Comment: I have tried it but it did not work in this case. DOn´t know why